# What is the proper order of style assets when using Prime NG and Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-cli, primeng

Just wondering when using a Prime NG theme for instance "Omega"... what is the proper ordering of the style sheets in the angular cli config. In the prime ng documentation is lists:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

And almost right below this documentation under Styles Configuration it lists:

```
"styles": [
 "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
 "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
 //...
 ],
```

Now I agree with the latter seeing as the theme which overrides primeng's base css is loaded last (cascading). But viewing the source on their demo site for their themes it looks as if they load the theme then primeng styles.

It just doesn't make sense to me to load the theme then load the base primeng styles. So which way is correct?

Even more confusing is the Prime NG book I have lists it as follows:

```
"styles": [
 "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
 "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
 "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
 ],
```

And the only way this method makes sense is if angular cli at one point rolled the styles from bottom to top (it currently rolls from top to bottom)

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

https://www.primefaces.org/omega-ng/#/

Comment: I used the one they have it PrimeNg book

Comment: @ChauTran did you create a custom theme? or just use their omega theme? Had you noticed any overriding css not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit more research I have discovered that order by and large doesn't matter. But it does play a factor if you are trying to override primeNG css styles. I didn't notice any problems with font-awesome's place in the order but for good measure I'd put the dependencies first. And for good measure you should order your styles:

`"styles": [
 "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
 "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
 //...rest of styles
 ],`

Because you never know if you'd like to override some of primeNG's base styles and it could create confusion if the order isn't correct.